# Malformed schema version 1,000

Tags: greendao

I have a problem whereby the generator is producing a malformed schema version. Does anyone know why this is the case?

```
public class MyDaoGenerator {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       Schema schema = new Schema(1000, "com.mydomain");
    ...
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
public class MyDaoMaster extends AbstractDaoMaster {
    public static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 1,000;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix will be available today in maven central. Update your greenDAO generator version to 1.3.1.

Comment: Did you downvote my answer? If so it would be just nice to leave a little comment why you downvoted. By the way: Updateing your blog with available new releases and changes would also be a great help.

Answer (score -1):

Probably this is a error coming from freemarker that occurs in greendao-generator <= 1.3.0.

Freemarker is used by greendao-generator to generate the `*.java`-files. If not configured freemarker uses a locale-sensitive output (for numbers).
See the [Freemarker Manual](http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_number_grouping)

If you want to use greendao with `schema-version > 999` you probably have to add this line in greendao-generator-project rebuild it and use the modified **greendao-generator.jar**. This causes all numbers used in the templates to be without grouping signs.

File **DaoGenerator.java (line 63)**:

```
config.setNumberFormat("#*");
```

Another way would be to manually edit the schema version in your generated file. But you would have to repeat this everytime you regenerate your code.